# Taking a screenshot of a user defined area

Tags: java, screenshot

I'm writing a screenshot app in Java and I've implemented most of the basic functionality. However I don't even know where to start when implementing the usual "click and drag selection" screenshot. Does anybody know how to do this?

The actual screenshot code if anyone needs it

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
Rectangle captureSize = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
BufferedImage bi = robot.createScreenCapture(captureSize);
```

Comment: Did that code solved your problem pdeuchler? Can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer so that we can close this question? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JFrame to select which they can resize.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Select screenshot area.");
frame.setSize(100,100);
frame.setResizable(true);
frame.setVisible(true)
```

Then have a button on the JFrame so when it is clicked, it will get the frames X, Y, Width and height and use that to program the robots screen capture function